# Destroying Clone in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, clone, destroy

Hi everyone Im a bit stuck here. I have my gameObject Enemy Spawn at a random time. But the thing is that I only want the Enemy to be in the game for say 5 seconds. The trouble is that I can't destroy the object at all. Here I wrote this code to try and destroy the Enemy Object:

```
public class SpawnManager : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject Enemy;
public float mytimer;
public float enemyHealth = 5.0f;

void Start()
{
    GameObject player = GameObject.Find("Player");
}

void spawnEnemy() {
    Transform enemy;
    GameObject enemySpawnPoint = GameObject.Find("EnemySpawn");
    enemy =  Instantiate(Enemy,enemySpawnPoint.transform.position,enemySpawnPoint.transform.rotation) as Transform; 
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == "EnemyTrigger") {
        mytimer = Random.Range(0,10);
        //Debug.Log("Now Destroying");
        Invoke("spawnEnemy", mytimer);
        Debug.Log("Spawn Normal");

        if(Enemy.name == "BloodyMary(Clone"){
            Destroy(Enemy, enemyHealth);
            Debug.Log("Now Destroying");
        }
        }
    }

    }
```

Everytime I run into the trigger it spawns a "BloodyMary(Clone)" which I am trying to destroy. Any advice?

Comment: did any of the answers provided answer your question correctly?

Answer (score 2):

In my eyes it would make more sense for the enemy to handle its own destruction. This would mean that an enemy is responsible for its own duration which I feel would make more sense if you're having possibly a ton of enemies on the scene at any time.

I would create a [co-routine](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) which would simply wait for 5 seconds and then call the `Destroy(gameObject)` function to destroy itself. It may look a little like this:

```
IEnumerator DeathTimer(float duration)
{
    yeild return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Then inside your 'Start()' method I would then call the co-routine (not done as a normal method). This would be done using something like this:

```
void Start()
{
    // calls the coroutine to start
    StartCoroutine("DeathTimer", duration);
}
```

*Note: By calling a co-routine using a string (like above) you can then call "StopCoroutine("MethodName");" which will stop the coroutine at any time. This would be better than passing in a method parameter into the StartCoroutine().*

This means your spawner is now purely responsible for spawning the enemies and they are responsible for their own death if they last for too long. Then you're not trying to manage multiple enemies on the spawner and you don't need to worry about tracking them in there.

I had a friend ask a very similar question the other day and he used this and it worked a treat.

Comment: I've edited the syntax in the first code snippets, a friend pointed out to me that it was slightly off.

Answer (score 1):

The code that says:

```
Invoke ("spawnEnemy", myTimer);
```

Is calling your `spawnEnemy()` function, which creates anther Enemy clone. It also does the call with a delay timer.

**If you don't want another Enemy just remove that part of the code**.

---

Also you are destroying with a timer. You can Destroy instantaneously with `Destroy(Enemy)`.

Comment: @Ghostdre if my answer solved your question, you can accept it to let others know it is solved. If I didn't please let me know as well.

Comment: Who ever down voted my answer please explain. If you make a valid point I will gladly delete my answer. However, I do know my answer is correct.

Comment: I don't see how this could be worth a down vote. Not sure who did it but it's worth an up vote for being the smallest answer. The only thing I would say is that the question is talking about destroying after 5 seconds and your answer is directed toward spawning every 5 seconds. Past that, have a +1.

Comment: @BlueHat Thanks. I see that the similar thing happened to you. +1 as well.

Comment: Thanks. It matters not though, the answers seemed as if they solved the problem. Hopefully it'll help others down the line.

Answer (score 1):

I see a typo, as you missed a closing parethesis on the name check. the reason that the linter didnt pick this up was because the parenthesis is in the string, so to the program it seems perfectly reasonable to check for "bloodymary(clone" instead of "bloodymary(clone)".

Answer (score 0):

Solution is straight forward.

use `Destroy(gameobject,5);` after u initiate that gameobject.

example

```
<-- line initiate gameobject -->
Destroy(gameobject,5);
```

which 5 is target second before gameobject will destroy.